Can't controll RGB backlight on ASUS Vivobook S14 M5406UA running ubuntu 22.04 LTS or 24.04 LTS
I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS (and have also tried with 24.04 LTS) on my ASUS Vivobook S14 M5406UA with an AMD Ryzen 7-8845HS.
The issue is that I can't control the RGB keyboard backlight. It is just on and cycles thru all the colors as it does whilst booting.
Setting the color would be nice, but at this point i would just like to be able to turn it off.
Thanks in advance for any help with this!
I have tried a few things:
1. xset
xset led off

This does nothing.
2. brightnessctl
sudo brightnessctl --device='asus::kbd_backlight' s 0

Resulting in
Updated device 'asus::kbd_backlight':
Device 'asus::kbd_backlight' of class 'leds':
       Current brightness: 0 (0%)
       Max brightness: 3

This displays the same behavior as pressing the backlight button on the keyboard (which also shows the new brightness level on screen), but nothing actually happens to the keybard backlight.
3. BIOS
I have looked in the BIOS, but found no option to turn off keyboard backlight.
4. OpenRGB
I have installed OpenRGB following these steps
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openrgb 

but when running it get the error:

Attempting to connect to local OpenRGB server.
Connection attempt failed
Local OpenRGB server unavailable.
Running standalone.
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID
[i2c_smbus_linux] Failed to read i2c device PCI device ID

Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. WARNING:One or more I2C/SMBus interfaces failed to initialize.RGB DRAM modules and some motherboards' onboard RGB lighting will not be available without I2C/SMBus.On Linux, this is usually because the i2c-dev module is not loaded.  You must load the i2c-dev module along with the correct i2c driver for your motherboard.  This is usually i2c-piix4 for AMD systems and i2c-i801 for Intel systems.See help.openrgb.org for additional troubleshooting steps if you keep seeing this message.

I have tried to load the i2c-dev module and drivers as described here, but after loading i2c-dev
sudo modprobe i2c-dev

I check if its loaded
lsmod | grep i2c_dev

And nothing comes up.
This might also be usefull?
    sudo dmesg | grep i2c
[    0.641968] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    6.432433] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ITE5570:00: failed to reset device: -61
[   12.576496] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ITE5570:00: failed to reset device: -61
[   18.720423] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ITE5570:00: failed to reset device: -61
[   24.864489] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ITE5570:00: failed to reset device: -61
[   25.888486] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ITE5570:00: can't add hid device: -61
[   25.929220] i2c_hid_acpi: probe of i2c-ITE5570:00 failed with error -61
[   25.940856] input: ASCP1200:00 093A:3016 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ASCP1200:00/0018:093A:3016.0001/input/input4
[   25.941007] input: ASCP1200:00 093A:3016 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ASCP1200:00/0018:093A:3016.0001/input/input5
[   25.941148] hid-generic 0018:093A:3016.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ASCP1200:00 093A:3016] on i2c-ASCP1200:00
[   27.246011] input: ASCP1200:00 093A:3016 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ASCP1200:00/0018:093A:3016.0001/input/input7
[   27.246215] input: ASCP1200:00 093A:3016 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ASCP1200:00/0018:093A:3016.0001/input/input8
[   27.246415] hid-multitouch 0018:093A:3016.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ASCP1200:00 093A:3016] on i2c-ASCP1200:00


Is this a dual boot machine?

@DavidDE no it is only running ubuntu

I asked because often these types of features are controlled by a Windows app.

Yes I did run windows on it for a few minutes before installing ubuntu and in windows you can control it all. I thought maybe it would just remember what was set in the windows settings, but when I ran 'Try ubuntu' it just went straight into the 'on' and changing color mode it is in now. But i guess that was running on the USB drive? Do you think having a small windows partition would stop this behavior in ubuntu @DavidDE?

No. But if it was dual boot and you turned off the color in Windows that might carry over to Ubuntu.

UPDATE: I have now tried in a dual boot setup, unfortunately the settings in windows do not carry over to Ubuntu :/ @DavidDE

Was worth a try. You could ask the computer maker but if it is like my Hyper x keyboard and mouse and headphones with lights they just told me too bad their app is only for Windows and I had to live with it..

BTW You might want to make your update an answer as it is what it is. At the bottom of the question is the answer your own question button. This way others that have same issue as you will know that at present there is no way to change it.

The solution by @PisonJay in the RGB Keyboard on ASUS Vivobook S 16 (5606) thread in Arch Linux Forums worked for me (M5406):

Just figured out. New ASUS laptops seem to enter an OOBE state at
startup where you cannot adjust keyboard backlight.   Need to
explicitly mark OOBE done by setting PCI0.SBRG.EC0.OOBS to 1 by
calling DEVS(0x5002f, 0x1) in WMI.   You can try following script,
# Run as root
cd /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi
echo 0x5002f > dev_id
echo 1 > ctrl_param
cat devs

Then Fn+F4 kbd backlight control should work.


This is a bit of a weird one... none of the above options worked. But my keyboard backlight is currently off.
This is how it seems to have happened (but i honestly cannot be sure):

Boot into your windows 11
Turn off keyboard backlight
windows settings > system > Recovery > advanced startup > restart now
After clicking restart now it just booted into Ubuntu and the backlight was off.

I will update this if there are any further developments.

Your last comment to me was it did not work, now I see it does as I suggested. BTW having a you-tube link is bad idea it may be gone later.

sorry, at the time it did not work @DavidDE. The changes only seem to carry across when restarting from windows as described above. Rebooting as normal did not carry the lighting changes across.
